# JPEG compression on Cortex M4

Tags: c, imageprocessing, cortex-m4

Is it possible to perform JPEG compression on a Cortex-M4 MCU? Are there existing libraries that can do this and can accept a 10-bit RAW RGB?

Answer (score 13):

Since the M4 core (and pretty much any other CPU used in a microncontroller) is [turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), the answer to your first question is *yes*, conditional on the other details of the MCU.

In particular, while the CPU itself is certainly capable of the instructions required to do JPEG compression, it must have enough RAM to implement whatever algorithm is chosen, so your question should include additional details of the specific MCU. A very quick Google search indicates that entry-level M4 MCUs include something like 64 KiB of RAM, which is almost certainly sufficient to perform at least a basic JPEG compression, since, wiht the right options, JPEG is generally a multi-pass *streaming* compressor (i.e., works its way though the data without needed random access). Exceptions include the DCT step, but that's only an 8x8 (perhaps up to 16x16 depending on chroma reduction settings) block, so only requires a small amount of RAM.

For more details, you need to dig into the JPEG standard, and decide what subset you want to support. Since you own the encoder, you can just generate JPEGs using the settings that work with your limitations. This is much different to writing a *decoder* for general JPEGs, since then you must support whatever options and modes the encoder chooses.

A good primer on memory use can be found in the [mozjpeg readme](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg/blob/master/libjpeg.txt) - it is brief, but at least includes key info, including the fact that progressive mode is generally out for your use case since it requires a whole-image buffer.

About your second question, it is unlikely that you'll find an existing library targeting the Cortex-M specifically that accepts RAW. You may have to combine a library that supports RAW decoding with one that supports JPEG encoding, and ensure that the interface between them allows streaming. Something like [mozjpeg](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg) may be a good start on the JPEG side. You may need to adjust how temporary results are stored depending on your exact configuration.

If you can't find a JPEG library already targeting this MCU, you may have to compile one of the existing free ones yourself. [This one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpegant.berlios/) looks promising since it explicitly targets MCUs and low memory use, but the linked author's page is 404, which is less promising.

Comment: Finite storage means NOT Turing complete.  While this theoretically means that PCs aren't Turing complete either, when you get down to embedded systems the difference definitely has practical consequences.  Nice treatment of a quick estimate on RAM consumption.

Comment: Your pedantry isn't useful here. If you read my reply, you'll see that I said that while the M4 core itself (which doesn't specify a RAM value) is turing complete, the practical answer depends on the amount of RAM in the particular MCU under consideration. Strictly using the infinite storage requirement for turing completeness makes a useless definition, yet reasonable people - even including writers of academic papers - still reasonably use without even mentioning the storage caveat.

Comment: From a quick search at ST.com's [STM32F4 product summary](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/microcontrollers/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus/stm32f4-series.html?querycriteria=productId=SS1577), the STM32F410 has 32kiB RAM, STM32F401 has 64-96kiB. All the rest have 128-256kiB, except the STM32F469 which has 384kiB. I found your link to mozjpeg readme useful too.

Comment: It seems like most options online and the one's suggested here (even the one's that were tested on ARM) target something that is able to run a full blown OS like Linux which this platform is unable to do.

Comment: They might "target" much platforms, in terms of syscalls for opening and writing to files, etc, but compression is just a simple in-memory operation, so you can use that part only for your purposes. Just isolate the compression code.

Comment: Yep, if it's just calls for read/write to files I should be isolate the compression code. Thanks!